# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to validate and format start_date and end_date using fluent validator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am given a request body to validate using Fluent Validation and then pass into the third party API.  Here is the request body.

RequestBody:

```
{
  "end_date": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
  "employee_code": "emp242ac120002",
  "start_date": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"
}
```

**EmployeeHistoryRequest:**

```
public class EmployeeHistoryRequest
{
    public string employee_code { get; set; }
    public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeeHistoryRequestValidator:**

```
public class EmployeeHistoryRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<EmployeeHistoryRequest>
{
    public EmployeeHistoryRequestValidator()
    {            
        RuleFor(p => p.employee_code)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Employee Code cannot be null")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Employee Code field is required. ERROR!");
        RuleFor(p => p.start_date)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Start Date cannot be null")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Start Date should not be empty. ERROR!");
        RuleFor(p => p.end_date)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("End Date cannot be null")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End Date should not be empty. ERROR!");
        RuleFor(x => x).Must(x => x.end_date == default(DateTime) || x.start_date == default(DateTime) || x.end_date > x.start_date)
                .WithMessage("End Date must be greater than Start Date");
    }
}
```

Here I am comparing the start_date and end_date.

Using Fluent Validation, how do I validate that each of the date (start_date and end_date) must be in this format: **yyyy-MM-dd**?

Comment: Did you try  .Must(date => DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd") ?

Comment: @jeb - I got this error:   No overload for method 'TryParseExact' takes 2 arguments       Then TryParseExact is highlighted

Comment: Can you show the `EmployeeHistoryRequest` class? Are both dates' datatype is string or DateTime type? If the dates' data type are `DateTime`, I don't see there is any reason that you validate the date in "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: .Must(date => DateTime.TryParseExact(x.start_date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out _)
Depending on the culture you want to accept.

Comment: @YongShun - I have added it in the updated code

Comment: I don't think you need to validate the DateTime with this "yyyy-MM-dd" format. If the request is sent with an invalid date time to API, by default the request body will deserialize to match your defined request body parameter type. If it fails to deserialize, the API will automatically return the response with a 400 Bad Request status code.

Answer (score 0):

Yoc can match the date format by using a custom method that compare Regex and return your result.
Try below

```
RuleFor(x => x.InputDate).Must(MatchDateFormat);
private bool MatchDateFormat(DateTime date)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(date.ToString(), @"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the properties as `DateTime` then is the binding process of ASP.NET that convert the values to datetime. In case of wrong format the validator is not invoked, since ASP.NET intercept the error first and directly return a `400 Bad Request` response.

If you want to treat input data as string then you must define them as string, and later convert the values when you use it:

```cs
public class EmployeeHistoryRequest
{
    public string employee_code { get; set; }
    public string start_date { get; set; }
    public string end_date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Personally I prefer to let binding issues to ASP.NET, and use FluentValidation only for "business rules".